# Implementing an intersection with linked-list stacks.

Tags: c++, stack, linked-list

Hi I have a homework assignment where I need to implement an intersection of two single lane streets over a two hour period. I need to adjust the phasing to get ideally less than 5 cars per queue, 9 is also acceptable.

It all works except something is amiss with the way my phasing is implemented and I just can't seem to get my head around the problem. The absolute best I can get is one queue being 0 or 1 and the other being 40+. I can't seem to get both of them under 9. I have got the problem down to my phase checks but can't think of a way to fix it. I understand that I want to favour Q1 slightly as the cars arrive to that slightly faster than Q2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

class Queue {
private:                         
    Node *listpointer;
public:                          
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    void push(int newthing);
    void pop();
    int top();
    bool isEmpty();
    int queueCount();
    void Queue::popTwo();
    bool Queue::twoOrMore();
};

Queue::Queue() {
//constructor
    listpointer = NULL;
}

Queue::~Queue() {
//destructor

}

void Queue::push(int newthing) {
//place the new thing on top of the Queue
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;             
    temp->data = newthing;
    temp->next = listpointer;
    listpointer = temp;
}

void Queue::pop() {
//remove top item from the Queue
    Node *p;
    p = listpointer;
    if (listpointer != NULL) {
        listpointer = listpointer->next;
        delete p;  
  }
}

int Queue::top() {
//return the value of the top item
    return listpointer->data;
}

bool Queue::isEmpty() {
//returns true if the Queue is empty
    if (listpointer == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int Queue::queueCount() {
    Node *temp;
    int count = 0;
    temp = listpointer;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        ++count;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return count;
    delete temp;
}

void Queue::popTwo() {
// remove the 2 top items from the stack
    Node *p;
    p = listpointer;
    if (listpointer != NULL) {
        listpointer = listpointer->next;
        delete p;
    }
    p = listpointer;
    if (listpointer != NULL) {
        listpointer = listpointer->next;
        delete p;                
    }
}

bool Queue::twoOrMore() {
// return true if the stack has at least two items
    if(listpointer==NULL || listpointer->next==NULL) return false;
    else return true;
}

//implement/copy your queue structure and functions above
//then, declare two instances:
//Queue Q1, Q2;
//if you want, make a separate function to change the 
//signals between the queues (either green or red)
//When the signal changes, one queue only is allowed to delete elements

Queue Q1, Q2;

int Q1phase = 30; //initial attempt
int Q2phase = 60; //initial attempt
const int Q1arrive = 18; //fixed 
const int Q2arrive = 22; //fixed
const int leave_rate = 10; //fixed, one car leaves either queue every 10 seconds

int car_id=0;
int clock=0;
bool Q1_green, Q2_green; //indicates which queue is opened, only one at a time

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //if(argc!=3) {printf("needs: Q1phase Q2phase\n"); exit(0); }
    //Q1phase=atoi(argv[1]);
    //Q2phase=atoi(argv[2]);
    if(Q1phase < 30 || Q2phase < 30) {printf("Minimum time for each queue to be closed is 30 seconds\n"); exit(0);}
    clock = 0;
    car_id = 0;
    Q1_green = true;
    Q2_green = false;
    int length_Q1, length_Q2;
    length_Q1 = 0;
    length_Q2 = 0;

    while (clock < 7200) {
        clock++;
        if (clock % Q1arrive == 0) {
            car_id++;
            //car_id join Q1
            Q1.push(car_id);
            length_Q1 = Q1.queueCount();
        }
        if (clock % Q2arrive == 0) {
            car_id++;
            //or car_id join Q2
            Q2.push(car_id);
            length_Q2 = Q2.queueCount();
        }

        if ((clock % Q1phase == 0) || (clock % Q2phase == 0)) {
            if (Q1_green == true) {
                Q1_green = false;
                Q2_green = true;
            } else {
                Q1_green = true;
                Q2_green = false;
            }
        }

        if (clock % leave_rate == 0) {
            if (Q1_green == true) {
                Q1.pop();
                length_Q1 = Q1.queueCount();
            }

            if (Q2_green == true) {
                Q2.pop();
                length_Q2 = Q2.queueCount();
            }
        }

    //ChangeSignal();//every second, check if it is time to change signals (phasing is important!)
    //After the signal change:
    //verify which queue is opened
    //either Q1 or Q2 will have the chance to delete one element (Q.Leave())
    //
    printf("at time %d:\nthe current length of Q1 is %d\n",clock,length_Q1);
    printf("the current length of Q2 is %d\n", length_Q2);
    //at the end of the simulation, both queues should have few cars
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tracked how the queues are changing over time, and how the lights are changing over time?  That might give a clue as to where the problem is, if not necessarily how to fix it.

Comment: A good chunk of your program is code reinventing a data structure which is already in the C++ language. Is this a required part of the homework? I.e. is the homework to simulate an intersection, or to make a queue data structure, or both? Reinventing the wheel distracts from the main purpose of the program and also puts you at the risk of wasting time debugging the queue data structure rather than the logic of the simulation. Homework is a drag so don't spend unnecessary time on it.

Comment: I have tracked how the lights change over time but it still confuses me. It is really to simulate the really simple intersection and make a queue data structure. So most of that is necessary but it was also given as a template by the lecturer. I thought that two phases were unnecessary also but I'm pretty sure they are required.

Comment: Why would there be two separate phases for flipping the light, `Q1_phase` and `Q2_phase`? Is that required? The changing of the light is a property of the intersection as a whole, shared by the two queues.  I think what you want is a different sense of phase. For instance out of every N clock period, you want Q1 to be green K of the time, and Q2 to be green N-K of the time. So if the intersection period is `T` and the phase is `P` you can test `(clock % T == P || clock % T == 0)` to drive the light switch.

Comment: For instance with T = 100, and P = 20, then one of the queues will have 20% of the time, and the other will have 80% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your total arrival rate exceeds the leave rate, so cars will have to backlog.

The total arrival rate is `1/22 + 1/18 =~ 0.1010` cars/sec.  This exceeds the leave rate of `0.1` cars per sec.

The light changes every 30 seconds (`Q1phase`) because `Q2phase` is a multiple of `Q1phase`. So basically the queues have an equal duty cycle.

Cars drain from each queue at half the total rate: 0.05 from one queue, 0.05 from the other (1/20).

Note that a leave rate of 1/20 is less than 1/18. So the queue with a 1/18 arrival will backlog.  The leave rate of 1/20 is greater than 1/22 so the queue with 1/22 arrival rate will not backlog.

This slight difference is not really slight! There is a world of difference between the arrival rate exceeding the leave rate or not exceeding the leave rate.

---

Oh, and here is how to calculate the cars in the backlogging queue:

Arrival rate: 1/18.
Leave rate: 1/20  (half of 1/10)
Total time: 7200 seconds:

7200 * (1/18) - 7200 * (1 / 20) ==  ????

**:)**

Comment: Okay I understand this however the only variables I can change are Q1phase and Q2phase.

Comment: Queuing is counter-intuitive sometimes. The **overall** arrival rate and leave rate does not predict a backlog of 40 cars. But the way you have to understand it is that the fast processing in one queue does not give you a **credit** which can be applied toward the backlog in the other queue. When the one queue has no cars waiting, that does not help the other queue in any way.

Comment: In other words, there is a potential in this problem for the backlog to be as little as about 7 cars. Why? Because that's the difference in the *system* arrrival and leave rate, multiplied by 7200. So I understand your task: manipulate the phases to try to get the queues down to close to what the overall system rates predict. Good luck!

Comment: I think the way your phases work may not be the way the prof intended, though. (Is any of that part the teacher's code?) You're simply testing whether the clock is divisible either by Q1Phase or Q2Phase and flipping the light. I would try to get some clarification on that matter from the prof or a teaching assistant. Or the class keener. :)

Comment: P.s. drop that unreachable `delete temp;` from the `queueCount` function. :)

Comment: I added a phase counter and managed to get the queues to 3 and 7 respectively. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great! I feel sorry for the drivers, though. In another 2 hours that will be 6 and 14, etc. They will just have to learn to put the pedal to the metal when the light turns green and not wait for `clock % leave_rate == 0`. :) Cheers ...